# What is :scm_verbose on capistrano?

Tags: git, capistrano

I searched on capistrano documentation but I didn't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the source](http://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/subversion.rb) (in this case subversion, but it works similarly for other scm modules):

```
def verbose
  variable(:scm_verbose) ? nil : "-q"
end
```

Unless `:scm_verbose` is `true`, the `-q` option is added to all svn commands, which suppresses output such as lists of files retrieved from the repository.

Comment: sorry but, what's the diference between -q and without -q ?

Comment: @Lucas, as I said above, -q suppresses output (usually a list of updated files from the repository).

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I was having problems with deploy via remote cache, then I added :scm_verbose, true to deploy.rb file and fixed the problem =]